# typedef to template type

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

What's wrong with the following?

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr SharedPtr;
```

GCC gives the following error:

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘shared_ptr’ with no type

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My mistake, typename should not be in there, but none of the existing answers are affected by this.

Comment: That code is invalid?? I never knew that! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ doesn't (yet) have "template typedefs" where you can "rename" a template like this.  This is a feature being added in C++0x, where such a "typedef" is called an "alias template."

The simplest workaround that works today is to use a class template with a nested typedef:

```
template <typename T>
struct SharedPtr
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Type;
};

// usage
typename SharedPtr<int>::Type sp;
```

Comment: Can you give reason as to why it's not valid in current C++? It seems kind of annoying that it isn't, and it suggests obvious behaviour.

Comment: @Matt:  It's just not a feature of the language in C++98/C++03.  I agree that it's annoying:  C++ has many annoyances and thankfully many of them have been rectified in C++0x.

Comment: The reason is just that shared_ptr is not a type, but a **template** for a type. On the other hand, `shared_ptr<int>` is a type and can be used in a typedef.

Comment: So can I `typename X Y`? Where X is a template type?

Answer (score 0):

C++11:

```
template<typename T>
using SharedPtr = boost::shared_ptr<T>:
```

Or you could use shared_ptr built into C++11:

```
template<typename T>
using SP = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```